# Why is the Asus M5A99X mainboard power LED blinking without mains attached?

Tags: motherboard

I have a M5A-99X Evo board by Asus. Recently, I found that the Power LED of the board is blinking in larger intervals (at least 1 minute dark, 1-2 seconds lit, then dark again; did not measure) *even if the mains are not connected to the power  supply*.

The manual does not have any information on this problem. I cannot find anything in the internets, as most blinking problems refer to issues with the mains attached and usually means some overloaded bus.

Here are the datapoints I collected so far:

- The board is rather new (less than one year), but to be sure I measured the BIOS battery (CR3032 button cell), which reads 3.03 V (open circuit) or 2.1 V (with LED attached).
- There are no active (i.e. currently connected to the mains) externally powered USB devices attached.
- It seems that the blinking stops while the battery is removed.
- The system has been shut down before. No suspend-to-disk or suspend-to-ram.

Does anyone have an idea what the LED might be telling us?

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the PSU's connectors from the board (both 24 pin and 8 pin connector)? What happens if you totally disconnect the board from the PSU?